# Repetitive information with JSON from ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a Web API in ASP.NET. I have a class `Recipe` and `Ingredient` which have a many-to-many relationship using hashset.

But now when I'm calling the function GetAllRecipes, it's giving me repetitive information about the recipe in the `Ingredient` object.
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZtGA.png)

I hope you understand, I can explain furthermore if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: I assume that this is JSON, if you don't want you `Ingredient` to link back to `Recipe` - you should add a [JsonIgnore] attribute above the field of `recipe` FK in the `Ingredient` class.
I'm still not sure tho how you didn't get a self-referencing loop here...

Comment: @LiranBo When I add the [JsonIgnore] attribute I get an exception saying "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'." With an inner exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"